# web service returns parent tag multiple times

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have  an webservice which fetches details from database and returns to the calling system.the output for a particular tag can have multiple items(Parent tag which will have multiple items) but instead it is returning same field again and again.Can anyone please help with this.

Current output

```
<emergencyEmails >raed@gmail.com</emergencyEmails >
<emergencyEmails >rad@gmail.com</emergencyEmails >
<emergencyEmails >read@gmail.com</emergencyEmails >
```

i want it to be like this

```
<emergencyEmails >
<item>raed@gmail.com</item>
<item>rad@gmail.com</item>
<item>read@gmail.com</item>
</emergencyEmails >
```

The email field is defined as an String array

```
package com.business.services;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(propOrder={"companyId", "emergencyEmails", "language",     "normalEmails", "timezone"})
public class ProfileDetails
{

private String companyId = null;

private String[] emergencyEmails = null;

private String language = null;



public String getCompanyId()
{
return this.companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(String companyId)
{
this.companyId = companyId;
}

public String[] getEmergencyEmails()
{
return this.emergencyEmails;
}

public void setEmergencyEmails(String[] emergencyEmails)
{
this.emergencyEmails = emergencyEmails;
}

public String getLanguage()
{
return this.language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language)
{
this.language = language;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the following annotations to "wrap" the array into an element:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="wrapper_tag_name")
@XmlElement(name="element_tag_name")
```

As you can see, the **@XmlElementWrapper** denotes the wrapper element name, while **@XmlElement** specifies the actual tag name of each email.

Now, if you annotate the getter method for emails, like

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="emergencyEmails")
@XmlElement(name="item")
public String[] getEmergencyEmails() {
    return emergencyEmails;
}
```

You should be fine.
Other option to annotate the field itself, in this case **@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)** for the class could be a solution